# How to get numbers of monitors

Tags: java, swing, awt

There are 2 monitors attached to my computer and I want to count them programmatically. How to do that with Java?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsConfiguration.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try next:

```
GraphicsEnvironment localGraphicsEnvironment = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
System.out.println(localGraphicsEnvironment.getScreenDevices().length);
```